# Convert date string from command line to datetime

Tags: sas

I want to convert the following date string `export v_date="20180101"` to datetime in SAS:

```
/* test.sas */

%let v_date = %sysget(v_date);
%put &=v_date;

data _null_;
  format v_dt yymmddn8.;
  v_dt = input(&v_date.);
  call symput('v_dt', v_dt);
run;

%put &=v_dt;
```

Run with `export v_date="20180101"; /sas/scripts/sas test.sas`

But I get this error:

```
1          %let v_date = %sysget(v_date);
2          %put &=v_date;
V_DATE=20180101
3          
4          data _null_;
5            format v_dt yymmddn8.;
6            v_dt = input(&v_date.);
                                  _
                                  388
                                  76
ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

7            call symput('v_dt', v_dt);
8          run;
```

How can I read this environment variable and convert it to a datetime macro variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep attention at calling input function and value that you write in macro variable. In addition, if you want to convert date in datetime, use [dhms](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p1b9d1kbo0czoxn1ouj1kcxwqzn1.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) function.

```
data _null_;
  format v_dt datetime.;
  v_dt = dhms(input("&v_date",yymmdd8.),0,0,0);
  call symput('v_dt1', v_dt);
  call symput('v_dt2', vvalue(v_dt));
run;
```

OUTPUT:

```
%put &=v_dt1;
```

> V_DT1=  1830384000

```
%put &=v_dt2;
```

> V_DT2=01JAN18:00:00:00